# Using a Secure SSL-app within a none -SSL VPN, still possible to be jeopardized data?

Tags: security, ssl, proxy, vpn

In some countries like Iran or china because of severe Internet censorship, people use a foreign VPN server to bypass government censorship.

Imagine we implement a none-SSL VPN for people who connect their phone to the Internet through this VPN. I want to know if they use a secure application within their phone which is secured by SSL like Instagram or WhatsApp, still, is there any security issue for the transmitted data between their phone and server?

I mean is it possible in this case their data would be sniffed by the government or others? (although the VPN is none-SSL but Instagram is SSL secured)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the scenario you have described, the VPN does not use SSL when communicating with the user device, but the secure application requires the use of SSL between the server and the client device.

The answer would depend on a few more things. Does the "severe internet censorship" flat out restrict the usage of the application? Take Instagram for example. Is the government banning the use of the application in its entirety or just certain aspects (such as filtering specific tags)? Sometimes the term "internet censorship" is used to mean one of these things but not the other (though most often the former).

Assuming the application is banned in its entirety, and the connection to the VPN is not secured by SSL, then the domain which is being banned would be visible to eavesdroppers at some point prior to the secure channel establishment (with SSL or rather TLS) between the client device and server. For example, it is likely the case that the DNS resolution of the domain is unencrypted (either at the client device level or communicating the query to the VPN). So, the eavesdropper (say, the government) would be able to see this and possibly act on it (say by dropping the request if they have a middlebox unknown to you).

So basically, if the connection to the VPN is not secured by SSL (or TLS) then there would be no benefit in using the VPN with regards to censorship.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the scenario is correct, the whole application is baned., But what about the secure channel? as I know the secure channel is established from the user's device and the service. so it means any data that is eavesdropped on would be encrypted they can not read it anymore. isn't it? how is it possible to read that data and decrypt it by the government ?

Comment: The eavesdropping in this case occurs prior to the secure channel establishment. The reason this works is because in order to create a secure channel between the user's device and the service, you first need to communicate on an insecure channel. Because the communication between the client and the VPN is not encrypted, information about the service which is required for setting up a secure channel is visible to eavesdroppers between the client and the VPN.